# Mysql query trivia

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Updated: Please assume, I will have exactly 4 elements in my version number x.x.x.x

```
Table xyz (id int, os varchar, version varchar)

id      os       version
1       mac      1.0.0.4
2       android  1.0.1.2
3       mac      1.0.0.14
4       mac      1.0.0.07
```

I want to find the maximum version number of each operating system.

```
select max(version), os from xyz group by os
```

but in the above data sample, it returns 1.0.0.4 as the highest version of mac, rather than returning 1.0.0.14. Is there any way to fix the above query? I know version is varchar :( If there is NO solution possible, then I can change datatype to other, but that will still not solve the issue.

Comment: As you are comparing strings, they are getting ordered and max means last. A way could be splitting and comparing each level's numbers as numbers.

Comment: did you know how many level may be used for version? Or number is random and not fixed/?

Comment: Yes, lets assume I will have exactly 4 elements in my version x.x.x.x

Comment: with fixed numbers set you may use my query a have posted in my answer. It a little heavy, but it must works if three fist numbers will have same length. Seems there are no other way.
Better solution is to parse and check version in caller code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the 4 parts in the version are all numbers and not bigger than 255, you can use the **[`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)** function, and its reverse `INET_NTOA()`:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(MAX(INET_ATON(version))), os 
FROM xyz 
GROUP BY os ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaab3/1)**

Comment: Wow .. never knew about INET_NTOA .. thanks @ypercube  Just curious, what woudl be the solution, if number goes beyond 255 ? 100.2345.343.3456

Comment: Well, this wouldn't work for sure. These 2 functions are used to convert IP strings to integers (for storing in a 4-byte column) and from integers to strings (to be shown in a report or other application)

Comment: I think taht you should then go for a solution that uses string functions (like @dan's answer) with SUBSTRING, LOCATE SUBSTRING_INDEX, etc, either in a query or putting it in a defined function, like Bacon suggests. And certainly normalizing the table would be the best (can't you create a new table to store these versions if you can't change this one?)

Comment: +1 If the version numbers are less then 256 this is the way to go. So this depends a lot on how are you generating the versions, the number could increase very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql uses text sort for this field when you try to get max:
    SELECT version FROM test ORDER BY VERSION;
1.0.0.14
1.0.0.4
1.0.07
1.0.1.2.4

But even if you try to cast this to integer, you will get
    SELECT version FROM test ORDER BY CAST(`VERSION` AS SIGNED);
1
1
1
1

And this really has a sense. How do you want MySQL to guess, what you want?
MySQL should be used to store data, and you should format it yourself.

A fine solution would be to use several fields for version:
id int, os varchar, **versionMajor int, versionMinor int, versionMoreMinor int, versionEvenMoreMinor int**

You should be able to sort and to format them as you wish.

Comment: I wish I would have that luxury to change schema so far ;) That would require even app code changes.

Answer (score 1):

It is ugly, but it's doing the job:

```
select t1.os,t1.version from xyz t1 where (t1.os,
       ((cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.version, '.', 1) as unsigned)+1)*1000
       +(cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.version, '.', -3), '.', 1) as unsigned)+1)*100
       +(cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.version, '.', -2), '.', 1) as unsigned)+1)*10
       +(cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.version, '.', -1) as unsigned))+1))
  =(select t2.os,
   max((cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.version, '.', 1) as unsigned)+1)*1000
      +(cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.version, '.', -3), '.', 1) as unsigned)+1)*100
      +(cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.version, '.', -2), '.', 1) as unsigned)+1)*10
      +(cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.version, '.', -1) as unsigned))+1) 
from xyz t2 where t2.os=t1.os);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d012b/64)

Answer (score 1):

What you'd really like to do here is use a `SPLIT` function, but that's not available in MySQL.  However, you can write a user-defined function that will do the same thing, or refactoring this function code into a view.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

[Source](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/).

Additionally, you may want to consider that the reason this is such a pain in the butt is because you're essentially violating first normal form.  A version number of the form you specify is actually four distinct values: major version, minor version, revision (or maintenance), and build.  Your table structure should use the same format:

`Table xyz (id int not null, os varchar not null, version_major int not null, version_minor int not null, version_revision int null, version_build int null)`

Then you just use an `ORDER BY` clause to sort the data.  You can use a calculated field or a view to display the formatted version number.

Now, I know why you chose to use a single field.  Version numbers are inconsistent, and many version numbers do not include revision or build values, other include letters, etc.  You can change the `int` to a `varchar` and cover 90% of cases in my experience, however.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to convert string to the integer and get MAX()

```
SELECT MAX( CONVERT( REPLACE( `version`, '.', '' ), UNSIGNED ) ) from xyz
```

**upd**

There are some another way with ending detection, but it doesn't work properly with minor version, maybe you will tune this heavy query to get it works well for you

```
SELECT `version`,
    CONVERT(
        CONCAT_WS( '.',
            REPLACE( SUBSTRING( `version`, 1, ( CHAR_LENGTH( `version` ) - LOCATE( '.', REVERSE( `version` ) ) ) ), '.', '' ),
            SUBSTRING( `version`, 1 + LOCATE( '.', REVERSE( `version` ) ) * -1  )
        ),
        DECIMAL ( 10, 3 )
    )
    FROM `xyz`
```

sorry, code improved

Comment: Lets assume I will have exactly 4 elements in my version x.x.x.x. I changed back the data set to original set. Your above query  gives the value with . removed. So how will I get the version in it original state?

Comment: Simple add ``version`` to the field set

Comment: thanks for your effort. But you missed, I have group by clause, that means I am trying to find maximum version for each os. And when I join group by it will give wrong value of maximum version number.

Comment: this will work select a.os, xyz.version from xyz, (SELECT os, MAX( CONVERT( REPLACE( `version`, '.', '' ), UNSIGNED ) )  as version from xyz group by os) a where a.os=xyz.os and CONVERT(REPLACE( xyz.version, '.', '' ), UNSIGNED) = a.version

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ntvf for idea.
This will do what I am looking for.

```
select a.os, xyz.version from xyz, 
  (SELECT os, MAX( CONVERT(REPLACE(`version`,'.',''),UNSIGNED)) as version from xyz group by os) a 
where 
   a.os=xyz.os and 
   CONVERT(REPLACE( xyz.version, '.', '' ), UNSIGNED) = a.version
```

Comment: Am I right that this will rank 1.0.0.10 as a higher version than 2.0.0.0?